# Drop down list with all months of the year using C# and ASPNET

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is my drop down list with all months of the year using C# and ASPNET.

```
private void mtmonthbind()
{
    DateTimeFormatInfo info = DateTimeFormatInfo.GetInstance(null);
    int currentMonth = DateTime.Now.Month;

    for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
    {
       ddlmonth.Items.Add(new ListItem(info.GetMonthName(i), i.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Every current month I have to compile a report from the previous month.

For example we are in January and today I have to fill out the December report.

I need to prevent accidentally selected a month other than the current month from the month list.

I tried this code but selecting the month of January blocks the compilation of the report of the month of December.

Any suggestion?

```
DateTime d = DateTime.Now;
d = d.AddMonths(-1);

string month = d.ToString("MMMM");
DateTime dt = new DateTime(1, Int32.Parse(ddlmonth.SelectedValue), 1);

if (d.Month.ToString() != ddlmonth.SelectedValue.ToString()
{
    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "Msg", "alert('Block');", true);
}
else
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: You don't need a dropdown list if you only allowed to select a current month

Comment: What Serge wrote above. Also, you selected "January", but you are comparing it with "December" (because of `d = d.AddMonths(-1);`), so obviously they are different